# PC + Realtime + VM =?

Tags: operating-system, real-time, rtos

This is a rather high-level "is this something worth investigating further" question as part of a programming project. Would this hypothetical be possible (and if so which OS would allow this)?

1. Some sort of vaguely realtime OS running in a VM on a modern PC. Doesn't need to be like a full-blown RTOS, but I would like the ability to respond to events in say 5 microseconds.
2. Direct hardware (e.g. I/O ports) access would make things easier
3. Able to use the HPET or some other mechanism for high-precision event timing.
4. Able to access the parallel port in EPP or ECP mode.

I have a few questions about the viability of such an arrangement.

1. Is there a vaguely realtime PC OS that can use the HPET?
2. Is it even possible to get ~5 us timing precision on a VM given the need to access the parallel port? I.e. would the VM driver for the parallel port itself preclude such tight timing?

Comment: A "real-time" OS cannot be hosted in a non-realtime OS. Unless the latter does not interfere at all - it's sort of possible with the modern Linux (isolcpu, nohz_full - all that kind of stuff). Now, you cannot use the host OS functionality to access your parallel port, you cannot allow context switches. You can either write a userspace parallel port driver, or use, say, an FPGA SoC and implement your own parallel port with your own user-space driver instead. Aslo, don't think you need an RTOS, just run a single thread instead.

Comment: "realtime" is a very precise term.  "vaguely realtime" is an oxymoron.  5 microseconds is very "hard" realtime; your "relaxation" of requirements (_"Doesn't need to be like a full-blown RTOS"_) kind of contradicts that.